# Margin affects other objects in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, margin

If you look at [this page](http://www.xn--existenzgrnder-im-netz-1lc.de/), you see 3 boxes (div#threeBlockOnTop), and a long box below (div#squeeze) with random content. The blue gaps over and under the 3 boxes should have the same size (around 30px). But in Firefox the gap over the 3 boxes is wider, because for some weird reason it is influenced by the top margin of the element below.

If you play with margin-top of div#squeeze in Firebug, you can see how it also changes the position of the 3 boxes above. What is wrong? And does that involve some legitimate property of CSS, that could be used for good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `<div class="clear"></div>` before the end tag of `div#threeBlockOnTop`.

It has to be after this end tag.

Answer (score 0):

use **tramsform3d** from css for performance

```
-webkit-transform:translate3d(-30px,0, 0);
-moz-transform:translate3d(-30px,0, 0);
transform:translate3d(-30px,0, 0);
```

this will not affct other objects

**and dont forget to reset all browsers**
each browser has his reset style and standard padding, margin,box-sizing ...
try this.

```
*{
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: `div#squeeze { 
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,30px, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0,30px, 0);
    transform:translate3d(0,30px, 0);
    margin-bottom:30px;
    }`

Comment: (WTH? I can't write blocks of code in comments?) What I posted in the last comment works in all browsers - except in Crome now. The actual question is: What is wrong with that page, that normal CSS doesn't work? It's just a bunch of boxes, that should have some gaps between them. Clearly a job for plain old CSS.

Comment: hi mate2code i dont know what is going on but if my answer was a solution to your problem it would be nice if you vote it thx otherweise please explain it again so that we find a solution

Comment: Hi kougiland. The problem is [still visible](http://www.xn--existenzgrnder-im-netz-1lc.de/) in Firefox, and your answer didn't help. You can see, that the sum of the gaps over and under the 3 boxes is too big. `translate` could now be used to move the 3 boxes a bit upwards, so both gaps would at least have the same size. But that's not the solution, because they would still be too big. What I'm even more interested in, than a solution, is isolating the problem, i.e. building something with few elements that shows the same behaviour. If you can do that, I will upvote it like a solution :)

Comment: es leigt daran, dass du nicht -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; benutzt viele gruesse

Comment: Why [Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit), when the problem is in Firefox? So, let's say `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;`. I will give it a try on monday.

Comment: actually you ve to reset for all browsers please fell free to check the update. and sure -moz-box-sizing: border-box; is perfectly correct

Answer (score 0):

Its related to browser specific css i think.. Try using `-webkit-padding for chrome` and remove padding with `-moz-pdding` for firefox..

Comment: `-webkit` doesn't work for firefox browser. please check your answer.